# Colour codes in python are not formatting correctly

Tags: python, colors, python-turtle

In Python 3.8.3 whenever I try to implement colored text in python like *\033[1;93m* it keeps on saying *[32m*. Can I have some help, because it doesn't usually happen?

Comment: Those color-codings are for console, are you using that? Seems like you are using IDLE or other IDE...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, you can only do it in the console. Too bad.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the module idle colours:

```
import sys
import random

# This will only work in IDLE, it won't work from a command prompt
try:
    shell_connect = sys.stdout.shell
except AttributeError:
    print("idlecolors highlighting only works with IDLE")
    exit()

# Map the colour strings to IDLE highlighting
USE_CUSTOM_COLORS = False       # Change to True if you want to use custom colours

global colormap

if USE_CUSTOM_COLORS:
    colormap = {"red": "COMMENT",
                "orange": "KEYWORD",
                "green": "STRING",
                "blue": "stdout",
                "purple": "BUILTIN",
                "black": "SYNC",
                "brown": "console",

                "user1": "DEFINITION",
                "user2": "sel",
                "user3": "hit",
                "user4": "ERROR",
                "user5": "stderr"}
else:
    colormap = {"red": "COMMENT",
                "orange": "KEYWORD",
                "green": "STRING",
                "blue": "stdout",
                "purple": "BUILTIN",
                "black": "SYNC",
                "brown": "console"}

# ---------------------------
# Functions
# ---------------------------

# Like the print() function but will allow you to print colours
def printc(text, end="\n"):
    # Parse the text provided to find {text:color} and replace with the colour. Any text not encompassed in braces
    # will be printed as black by default.
    buff = ""
    for char in text:
        if char == "{":
            # Write current buffer in black and clear
            shell_connect.write(buff, colormap["black"])
            buff = ""
        elif char == "}":
            # Write current buffer in color specified and clear
            tag_write = buff.split(":")
            shell_connect.write(tag_write[0], tag_write[1])
            buff = ""
        else:
            # Add this char to the buffer
            buff += char

    # Write the chosen end character (defaults to newline like print)
    sys.stdout.write( end )


# Individual colour functions
def red(text):
    return "{"+ text + ":" + colormap["red"] + "}"

def orange(text):
    return "{"+ text  + ":" + colormap["orange"] + "}"

def green(text):
    return "{"+ text + ":" + colormap["green"] + "}"

def blue(text):
    return "{"+ text  + ":" + colormap["blue"] + "}"

def purple(text):
    return "{"+ text + ":" + colormap["purple"] + "}"

def black(text):
    return "{"+ text  + ":" + colormap["black"] + "}"

def brown(text):
    return "{"+ text + ":" + colormap["brown"] + "}"

def randcol(text):
    color = random.choice(list(colormap.keys()))
    return "{"+ text + ":" + colormap[color] + "}"

# User defined colours
def user1(text):
    return "{"+ text + ":" + colormap["user1"] + "}"

def user2(text):
    return "{"+ text + ":" + colormap["user2"] + "}"

def user3(text):
    return "{"+ text + ":" + colormap["user3"] + "}"

def user4(text):
    return "{"+ text + ":" + colormap["user4"] + "}"

def user5(text):
    return "{"+ text + ":" + colormap["user5"] + "}"
```

And here is how you might use it:

```
from idlecolors import *
printc( red("Red text") )
printc( "If you add " + red("red") + " to " + blue("blue") + ", you get " + purple("purple") )

# Print a line in a random colour
printc( randcol("This is a random colour") )

# Print each word in a random colour
mytext = "This is a random piece of text which I want to print in random colours"
mytext = mytext.split(" ")
for word in mytext:
    printc(randcol(word), end=" ")
```